# Can I use IronPython in Linqpad?

Tags: ironpython, linqpad

I love Linqpad and I'm studying IronPython. Can I use Linqpad as my "code scratchpad" when I'm doing some IronPython exercises? Just wondering. :)

Thanks.

---

**Update:**

According to Joe Albahari, there's moderate support for adding other languages, so it will probably be added at some stage.

See IronPython/IronRuby support request [link](http://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/359780-ironpython-ironruby-support-would-be-nice-) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You might try asking Joe if there are any plans for it on the [linqpad forum](http://forum.linqpad.net/). He's a nice chap.